# How to use axios.all with post requests that have headers and body?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am accessing a remote API using a ReactJS application. I need to do multiple POST requests, then do an action after they're all done. I came to the conclusion that using `axios.all` is the best way to do this. I tried the code below:

```js
var body = {
  pov: [
    "Annual Value",
    "&CurrYear",
    "Fund Transfer",
    "Project NSP",
    "Input View",
    "Activity NSP",
    "Account NSP",
    "Location NSP",
    "Department NSP",
    getStageNameEN(vNum),
    "Line Item NSP",
    transfer,
    segment
  ],
  columns: [["Flag"]],
  rows: [{ row: [entity], data: [flag] }]
};

promises.push(
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "/api/setFlag",
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Basic " + localStorage.getItem("auth"),
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    data: body
  })
);

axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
  //do something here
});
```

The requests were sent before the `axios.all` part, since when I deleted it the same happened. When `axios.all` was included, the code was stuck in a loop, or at least didn't execute what is inside.

When I changed the axios part to use `axios.post`, I keep getting an error.

What is the correct way to use `axios.all` in order to execute multiple POST requests that each have headers and bodies?

Comment: If you search for [`axios.spread` in the documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios) you will see an example of using it with `axios.all`. Maybe that's what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me also - I wanted to upload multiple files async. I resolved it by doing the following:

```
let requests = [];
let _cmp = this;
for (let i = 0; i < _cmp.images.length; i++) {
    requests.push(function() {
        return _cmp.storePhotoRequest(_cmp.images[i]);
    });
}

_cmp.$http.all(requests.map(function(r) {
    return r();
})).then(axios.spread(function() {
     /*more code*/
})
```

Store photoRequest do this

```
storePhotoRequest: function(image) {
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append('photo', image.file);
    return this.$http.post('some', form, config);
}
```

Comment: Just wrap the axios request in one anonymous function and called it when use map() on the all() method